# Outlook - Find email of account the message was sent to

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

My client has a problem and it mean I have a problem:

In the case where email recipient have multiple emails configured in Outlook - 
I have one yahoo email account and 2 Exchange accounts from different Exchange servers.

When processing incoming email in ProcessItemAdd event handler (Add-In Express)
I try to discover what account out of 3 this email was sent to:

So my first method is:

```
                         Outlook.MailItem re = ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Reply();
                        if (re != null)
                        {
                            var thisEmail = "";
                            Outlook.Account account = re.SendUsingAccount;
                            if (account != null)
                            {
                                thisEmail = account.SmtpAddress;
                                Log.VerboseFormat("thisEmail = {0}", thisEmail);

                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(re);
                                re = null;

                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(account);
                                account = null;
```

It works perfectly on my machine with Outlook 2010 32bit, but does not work on my client machine with Outlook 2010, returning empty string.
So my second (backup method) is:

```
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisEmail))
                                {
                                    // This requires that in the case of Exchange account it should be cached Exchange account.
                                    thisEmail = (string)mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8580001F");
                                    Log.VerboseFormat("Got receiver account email address from schema: {0}", thisEmail);
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Again this works perfectly on my machine but does not work on client machine, returning empty string.
I did verify that in my client's case the sender is Exchange account with caching...

BTW, it works fine on client machines when sender is non-Exchange and receiver is Exchange account...

Is there any other method that reliably can determine what account the email was sent to (in case of multiple recipients).

Here is my latest code that works on 2010/2013 but not on 2007. On the latter account is null and x-header returned empty:

```
                            Outlook.MailItem re = ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Reply();
                        if (re != null)
                        {
                            var thisEmail = "";
                            Outlook.Account account = re.SendUsingAccount;
                            if (account != null)
                            {
                                thisEmail = account.SmtpAddress;
                                Log.VerboseFormat("thisEmail = {0}", thisEmail);

                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(re);
                                re = null;

                                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(account);
                                account = null;
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisEmail))
                                {
                                    string x_headers = (string)mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F");
                                    thisEmail = FindTargetEmail(x_headers);
                                    Log.Verbose("Extracted target email address from MIME x-headers: {0}", thisEmail);

                                } 
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                                Log.Verbose("account is null...");

                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(thisEmail))
                                {
                                    string x_headers = (string)mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F");
                                    thisEmail = FindTargetEmail(x_headers);
                                    Log.Verbose("Extracted target email address from MIME x-headers: {0}", thisEmail);
                                }

                            }
```

EDIT:
Well, it is not over yet. Although it works well on all machines that I have client reports a problem on 2010. It is very strange problem.
User user1@domain1.com (cached Exchange account) sends email to user user2@domain2.com (gmail account). When I parse the MIME header on the receiver side with the above code in order to get the address that this email was sent to...I get back user1@domain1.com instead of user2@domain2.com !! How this is possible? I know that I am parsing the right part of the header (do I ?) and on my machines it returns the correct result...why it does not happen on SOME of my client's machines??

Experts, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it on your client's machine? Is it because Account.SmtpAddress is null? Or because MailItem.SendUsingAccount is null? You should be able to look at the object without installing any debugging tools using OutlookSpy - select the message, clicn Item button on the OutlookSpy toolbar, select SendUsingAccount property, click Browse.

Comment: accountSmtpAddress returns empty string.
As I mentioned it works on my machines but on some of my client's machines accountSmtpAddress returns empty string. The second method with PropertyAccessor also return nothing...My client is not technical and I cannot start installing OutlookSpy - besides that I don;t have it...I am trying the 3rd and most promising method of parsing MIME x-headers.

Comment: What kind is the problematic account?

Comment: this is Gmail account I believe.

Comment: Also on 2007 the account returns null and x-header returned empty.

Answer (score 0):

Typically a [Store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862128.aspx) in the Outlook profile represents a separate account. You may handle the [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx) event of the Items class (ProcessItemAdd in ADX terms) in each store to identify the account the email message was sent to.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work...I have ProcessItemAdd and the only parameter it passes is object item which is in my case Outlook.MailItem from this you can find folder:
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = FolderObj as Outlook.MAPIFolder;

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work...I have ProcessItemAdd and the only parameter it passes is object item which is in my case Outlook.MailItem from this you can find folder:
Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = FolderObj as Outlook.MAPIFolder; and then even the store = folder.Store; hoever store has no email address the mail item was sent to - sometimes store name is email address but this is not necessarily email address - could be just text...my latest news - code that I introduced works fine on Outlook 2010 / 2013 but not on 2007 - the x_header returned from PropertyAssessor is empty...